# ValueError: Related model u'app.model' cannot be resolved

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have two applications (`ook` and `eek` say) and I want to use a foreign key to a model in `ook` from a model in `eek`. Both are in `INSTALLED_APPS` with `ook` first.

In `ook.models.py`, i have:

```
class Fubar(models.Model):
    ...
```

In `eek.models.py`, I have:

```
class monkey(models.Model):
    external = models.ForeignKey('ook.Fubar', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

The migration generated is:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('eek', '0002_auto_20151029_1040'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='monkey',
            name='external',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='ook.Fubar', null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

When I run the migration, I get this error:

```
   ...
   1595             raise ValueError('Foreign Object from and to fields must be
the same non-zero length')
   1596         if isinstance(self.rel.to, six.string_types):
-> 1597             raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
   1598         related_fields = []
   1599         for index in range(len(self.from_fields)):
ValueError: Related model u'ook.Fubar' cannot be resolved
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are `ook` and `eek` included in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall: Yes, they are and `ook` is before `eek`.

Comment: 'ook.models.Foobar' maybe?

Comment: @cdvv7788: It would not make any difference since I added `Fubar` to the top `__init__.py` on `ook`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because You have `ForeignKey` in operations, You must add a `ook` to `dependencies`:

```
dependencies = [
    ('ook', '__first__'),
    ('eek', '0002_auto_20151029_1040'),
]
```

Django migrations have two "magic" values:

- `__first__` - get module first migration
- `__latest__` - get module latest migration

Comment: what '__first__' means ? I have the same problem but it doesn't working for me

Comment: __first__  means find the app where that "model" was originally created, find it..

Comment: Why is this not generated automatically?

Comment: @Sören It's probably bug. `migrations.AlterField` on `ForeignKey` don't generate `dependencies` (tested on 1.11.4)

Comment: what is "ook" and "eek"? "foo" and "bar"?

Comment: @greenie-beans `ook` and `eek` are a application names.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup ah I see, thanks for the clarification. Those are kind of confusing variable names for this example.

Answer (score 29):

Try running migrations one by one for every model.

This way you can debug the `app` you are facing problem with

```
python manage.py migrate appmname
```

Answer (score 10):

I just got the same error, but referring to a model that was declared as part of the same migration. It turned out that the first `migrations.CreateModel(...)` referred to a not yet declared model. I manually moved this below the declaration of the referred model and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, It was the cache and previous migrations that resulted in this error. I removed `__pycache__` and migrations folder and then re-run the migrations command and it worked.

Remember, when you'll do `python manage.py makemigrations` it won't see any new migrations and will console output `no changes detected`. You'll have to do `python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name` instead to make things work.

Comment: this is the fastest solution for me

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your situation, using `run_before` may resolve your issue.

For me, I hit the error while running `Applying admin.0001_initial..` so django admin was not respecting the order of operations. I added this to my migration file that was adding a new user table:

```
    run_before = [
        ('admin', '__first__'),
    ]
```

This resolved my issue.

The detail of my specific issue is that django admin's migration [depends on the first migration](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4c85beca9d8bf24573d741e26ea36295c69af5b2/django/contrib/admin/migrations/0001_initial.py#L9) of my app whereas my User is added much later. This means my user table doesn't exist when admin tries to run migrations.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when trying to use a child model of a base model as a foreign key. It makes sense that it didn't work because there's not an id field on the child model. My fix was to use the parent on the key. Unfortunately this was not immediately intuitive and set me back a couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it looks like this bug was not fixed yet when you scroll down to the bottom.

[Django ValueError: Related model cannot be resolved Bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22319)

I am using 1.11.7, they are talking about 1.9.3.

It worked everything on localhost, but was always failing on Heroku, so I tested all the options/answers above and nothing worked.

Then I have noticed, localhost DB in Admin I had 1 profile created (1 DB record), went to Heroku and DB has 0 records for Profile table so I have added 1, pushed the migration, python manage.py migrate and all it went OK.

That validates that I did not need to change any of those migrations manually that all is working.

Maybe it will help to someone.

migrations

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.7 on 2017-11-23 21:26
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
         ('blog', '0005_blog_author'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
             model_name='blog',
             name='author',

field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
to='core.Profile'),
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

order of `dependencies` is too important.

in your case, `ook` must be created first then depend `eek` on it.

```
dependencies= [
    ('ook', '0001_initial'),
    ('eek', '0002_auto_20151029_1040'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error:

> ValueError: Related model 'feed.customuser' cannot be resolved

to solve this,I did `py manage.py migratrations app_name` and I did same for all the apps separately.

I also did `py manage.py migrate app_name`  separately to all the apps.

this worked for me.