# Getting issue with automatic handling rename migrations with django models and its field

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am getting issue with handling renaming automatically in Django models and its field

```
# Generated by Django 2.2 on 2020-07-14 13:16

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('projectAPI', '0007_auto_20200713_1226'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name='Store',
            new_name='Site',
        ),
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name='UserStore',
            new_name='UserSite',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='installation',
            old_name='store',
            new_name='site',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='site',
            old_name='store_name',
            new_name='site_name',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='usersite',
            old_name='store',
            new_name='site',
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='installation',
            unique_together={('site', 'installation_name')},
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='usersite',
            unique_together={('site', 'user')},
        ),
    ]
```

Getting issue with old model name store when

python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate projectAPI

```
 File "/home/chillmaster/chillmaster/chillmaster_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'projectAPI.Store' cannot be resolved
```

I have checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497027/7828402 but not get the solution I have tried to edit like in migration dependencies but not work for me

```
('projectAPI', '__first__')
```

I know deleting migration and DB data it will work but I don't want to lose data in DB please help with solutions
Thanks in advance