# Custom User model changes never migrate

Tags: python, django, django-models

I made the mistake of not using a custom user model for the first migration and I paid the price by having to delete all the migrations and `makemigrations` and `migrate` again as I switched the project to use my custom user.

models.py

```py
"""
 Changes are never picked by makemigrations
"""
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, blank=False,
                validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)])
    email = models.EmailField('Email Address', unique=True, blank=False)
    FCM_ID = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Everytime I made any changes to the custom user, I have had to delete all migrations related files and apply migrations again just to get past the errors- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496333/valueerror-related-model-uapp-model-cannot-be-resolved) SO answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682155/django-user-registration-with-error-no-such-table-auth-user).

Now I realized that I needed a newer change, but migrations are not detected after changing the User model. The only solution I have is to delete the migrations again! So far I have done this chore like 5 times and I am tired, what am I doing wrong?

I have tried `python3 manage.py makemigration <app_name>`, and of course, the custom user model is defined in `settings.py` using `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Comment: make sure you have __init__.py in your app having the custom user model.

Comment: I have the same issue but it only happens in github workflow. Not in local system